# In Unity, how to delete a component via script when deleting another component via the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, editor

Context : I'm editing a prefab, I have two components on it, both are custom scripts.

When editing a prefab, I want to remove the component Container Sync at the same time that I remove the component Container Descriptor in the editor by right clicking it and clicking on Remove Component. See the picture below.

[image: components I want to delete]

In ContainerDescriptor, I have a reference towards the ContainerSync script.

```
 public class ContainerDescriptor : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public ContainerSync containerSync;
 }
```

I tried to use the method OnDestroy() of the ContainerDescriptor script, but it's not called when removing ContainerDescriptor that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1151153/remove-component-method-call.html) there is a solution at least for if you remove that component via the context menu like you do.

Using [`[ExecuteAlways]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html) the event message calls that usually are only called in PlayMode do also get called in Edit and in Prefab mode!

You can do something like e.g.

```
[ExecuteAlways]
public class ContainerDescriptor : MonoBehaviour
{
     public ContainerSync containerSync;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
     private void OnDestroy ()
     {
         if(containerSync)
         {
             if(Application.isPlaying)
                 Destroy(containerSync);
             else
                 DestroyImmediate (containerSync);
         }
     }
#endif
}
```

Note though that specifically for prefabs this might still fail since afaik neither `Destroy` nor `DestroyImmediate` can be used inside of prefabs (see [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/programmatically-destroy-gameobjects-in-prefabs.591907/))

Comment: It seems to be working for prefabs as well, at least DestroyImmediate does.